# Example open source WPF touch application?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, touch

I'm looking for some WPF applications specifically designed for touch. Preferably they'd be open source. I don't really care about the apps function, I just want to get some design ideas for a Win7 WPF touch app I'll be writing. I'd like to see what can be done with WPF touch.

Thanks

Comment: Might be able to pick up some ideas at this blog http://stephangerbling.blogspot.com . I didn't find any project downloads though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of great silverlight example apps ( http://www.Silverlight.net/showcase/ ) which are very similiar to WPF apps.  Worth a shot if you just want design ideas, Plus they are web based so you don't have to install them.

Also can look at Windows 8 Developer Preview (if you know someone with it or have the time to install it).  there are a bunch of pre-loaded touch based apps there too, also very much like WPF

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using the Surface 2.0 SDK.  It has a lot of controls that are optimized for touch interactions.

Anson Tsao also did a writeup of how to directly use the Touch APIs in WPF 4, the first post of which is here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2009/12/03/multi-touch-in-wpf-4-part-1.aspx
There's a zip file you can download with examples of how you can incorporate multitouch functionality.

If you're really just looking for design inspiration, dig more into Surface.  There has been a lot of great thinking there about how to create multiuser multitouch experiences.

Comment: I had planned on probably using the Surface SDK, just surprised I can't find one demo app.